# Streaming Raster layer does not export with map at large paper size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, pdf

I have a layer in an MXD which is a streaming raster layer from a web tile service, it is a mosaic.  If I output the map as a PDF at Arch C size or smaller the raster shows up in the PDF fine, if I choose Arch D or larger the raster does not show up in the exported PDF.  I have set my visibility scales on the raster layer just in case and it is within the range of visibility.  The layer shows fine on my screen in layout and data view of ArcMap.  It is a streaming layer of orthophotos from Planet.  RUnning 10.3.1 but also reproduced in 10.6

Anyone else have this behaviour and know a fix?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Is your local cache big enough? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/managing-your-local-display-cache.htm is there a restriction on Planet data? Have you tried lowering your image quality? or your output settings https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/administering-desktop/advanced-arcmap-settings-utility.htm giving more memory to the output process?

Comment: No error messages.  Can't change local cache as my layer properties window does not match the ESRI help page linked above, I have no cache tab.  No idea on Planet data restriction but don't think so as other PC could export it fine.  I did give more memory to output operation, thanks.  The one thing that seemed to fix it was reducing image quality in the export file dialog settings.  One down from "best" and the raster started showing up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcmap exported with the raster in the background after I reduced the quality settings of the output in the Export Map dialog window.

Different PCs in the office handled the export differently, with some able to export at "best" quality and some only showing the raster when quality was reduced, but this was counter-intuitive as our newest machine with lots of RAM needed to have the quality reduced in order to work, but a much older PC with less RAM was able to export at "best" quality and still show the raster.